# Explanation on const in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, constants

I have seen a lot of similar questions for C and C++ but none for Objective-C. Actually i understand difference between `pointer to constant object` and `constant pointer to object` in C but the following still confuses me:

```
NSString const* a = @"a";
NSString *const b = @"b";
const NSString *c = @"c";
```

what is the difference between these three? I cannot change value of `b` so probably this is the pointer to constant object (am i right?) but what about the rest? Thanks